# Unable to find QuantLib-Python bindings for Synthetic CDO

Tags: programming, quantlib, cdo

I am trying to price a Synthetic CDO using QuantLib Python. Unfortunately, I am unable to find any suitable CDO pricing engine ported into Python. They do exists but in C++ as per my preliminary research (MidPointCDOEngine, IntegralCDOEngine etc.). Any guidance in this direction would be highly appreciated!!. Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe the CDO instrument has been ported. Maybe open that issue for QuantLib SWIG on github